# How to use geo/s2 library to determine a LatLong lies inside a radius from another LatLong in Go?

Tags: go, geo, s2

I have tried this code , couldn't find any examples for geo/s2 for Go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/golang/geo/s2"
)

func main(){
    rect := s2.RectFromLatLng(s2.LatLngFromDegrees(12.9279,77.6271))
    rect = rect.AddPoint(s2.LatLngFromDegrees(12.9081,77.6476))
    isThere := rect.ContainsLatLng(s2.LatLngFromDegrees(12.9177,77.6233))

    fmt.Printf("%+v", rect.Hi())
    fmt.Printf("%+v", rect.Lo())
    println(isThere)

}
```

Comment: I think you need Cap.ContainsPoint. https://github.com/golang/geo/blob/e41ca803f92c4c1770133cfa5b4fc8249a7dbe82/s2/cap.go#L178

Comment: Thanks @Not_a_Golfer , Cap.ContainsPoint is the one

Comment: Maybe add your solution as an answer so people looking for it in the future can find it?

Answer (score 0):

[This is not my answer, but many people don't even go through the comments and may miss the information]

As [@not-a-golfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239701/not-a-golfer) said [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560147/how-to-use-geo-s2-library-to-determine-a-latlong-lies-inside-a-radius-from-anoth/62759654#comment95921652_54560147) you should use https://github.com/golang/geo/blob/e41ca803f92c4c1770133cfa5b4fc8249a7dbe82/s2/cap.go#L178